# LVM: how to always show Pfree in GB

Tags: linux, lvm

`pvs` shows `Pfree` in MB or GB:

```
pvs
 PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize PFree  
  /dev/sda2  vg50 lvm2 a--  1.09t 950.16g


   pvs
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  vg60 lvm2 a--  149.51g 944.00m
```

How we can get `Pfree` only in GB?

Or is there another LVM command that always shows `Pfree` in GB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can force `pvs` (and other LVM tools) to use a specific unit with [the `--units` option](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pvs.8.html#OPTIONS):

```
pvs --units g
```

will show all values in gibibytes (multiples of 1024). Use

```
pvs --units G
```

if you want gigabytes (multiples of 1000).